# Android Flip animation rotation point

Tags: android, android-animation

hi guys i have manged to animate an image by following the android flip animation tutorial, but I have this issue I am try to animate a butterfly like in the app `ibutterfly` and I am using this method to apply the transformation

```
protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
    final float fromDegrees = mFromDegrees;
    float degrees = fromDegrees
            + ((mToDegrees - fromDegrees) * interpolatedTime);

    final float centerX = mCenterX;
    final float centerY = mCenterY;
    final Camera camera = mCamera;

    final Matrix matrix = t.getMatrix();

    camera.save();

    camera.rotateY(degrees);



    camera.getMatrix(matrix);
    camera.restore();

    matrix.preTranslate(-centerX, -centerY);
    matrix.postTranslate(centerX, centerY);

    matrix.preScale(scaleType.getScale(scale, interpolatedTime),
            scaleType.getScale(scale, interpolatedTime), centerX, centerY);

}
```

the problem I am having is the image rotate from the middle point but I need to change the rotate axis to left corner is there a way to do that, I tried everything I know but I cannot manage that, if some one can help me with this i will be much thankful

this is the tutorial i followed on [Google Code](https://code.google.com/p/android-3d-flip-view-transition/).

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://github.com/openaphid/android-flip) library?

Comment: in there is there a way to define the rotation axis, it only rotate around the middle, can not change it, i dont know may be i am wrong, but i think this library not helping thanx for the answer :)

Comment: Well, you will have to explore the code and make some changes but I think that library is the closest of what you require. Spend time with it and you can sure modify it. I will try but will have to do in weekends as I am busy with my projects. So, good luck!

Comment: Glad to help, hope it goes well for you. Let me know if you are able to crack it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FInally Found a way to change the rotation axis. the issue was where i was looking the above method is not the place to change the rotation axis just had to change the below method

```
public static Animation[] flipAnimation(
            final View fromView,
            final View toView,
            FlipDirection flipDirection,
            long duration, Interpolator interpolator) {
        Animation[] result = new Animation[2];
        float centerX;
        float centerY;

        centerX = 0.0f; // Simpliy had to change the centerX value here 
        centerY = fromView.getHeight(); 

        Animation outFlip = new FlipAnimation(
                flipDirection.getStartDegreeForFirstView(),
                flipDirection.getEndDegreeForFirstView(), centerX, centerY,
                FlipAnimation.SCALE_DEFAULT,
                FlipAnimation.ScaleUpDownEnum.SCALE_NONE);
        outFlip.setDuration(duration);
        outFlip.setFillAfter(true);
        outFlip.setInterpolator(interpolator == null ? new AccelerateInterpolator()
                : interpolator);

        AnimationSet outAnimation = new AnimationSet(true);
        outAnimation.addAnimation(outFlip);
        result[0] = outAnimation;

        // Uncomment the following if toView has its layout established (not the
        // case if using ViewFlipper and on first show)
        // centerX = toView.getWidth() / 2.0f;
        // centerY = toView.getHeight() / 2.0f;

        Animation inFlip = new FlipAnimation(
                flipDirection.getStartDegreeForSecondView(),
                flipDirection.getEndDegreeForSecondView(), centerX, centerY,
                FlipAnimation.SCALE_DEFAULT,
                FlipAnimation.ScaleUpDownEnum.SCALE_NONE);
        inFlip.setDuration(duration);
        inFlip.setFillAfter(true);
        inFlip.setInterpolator(interpolator == null ? new AccelerateInterpolator()
                : interpolator);
        inFlip.setStartOffset(duration);

        AnimationSet inAnimation = new AnimationSet(true);
        inAnimation.addAnimation(inFlip);
        result[1] = inAnimation;

        return result;

    }
```